# attempting to use WinRT binding to IsChecked

Tags: binding, radio-button, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In the code below, the no breakpoints in the converter are ever hit. Clicking on the radio buttons doesn't do anything to change the active control. It's like the IsChecked doesn't even trigger a change event. Any ideas? This is WinRT code.

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestBinding.MainPage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestBinding"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:EqualsToBoolConverter x:Key="equalsToBoolConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>
<Page.TopAppBar>
        <AppBar IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <RadioButton
                    Style="{StaticResource TextRadioButtonStyle}"
                    Name="goItem1"
                    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=flipView,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource equalsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=item1}, Mode=TwoWay}">Go 1</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton
                    Style="{StaticResource TextRadioButtonStyle}"
                    Name="goItem2"
                    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=flipView,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource equalsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=item2}, Mode=TwoWay}">Go 2</RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>
    <FlipView
        Name="flipView"
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Margin="100"
        Padding="10"
        SelectedIndex="0">
        <FlipViewItem Name="item1">
            <TextBlock Text="item1"/>
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem Name="item2">
            <TextBlock Text="item2"/>
        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>
</Page>
```

Comment: It may help to take a look at the Debug Output Panel. Binding errors will be reported there.

Comment: Binding errors are not reported in the Debug Output Panel. This is WinRT and they have issues with that.

Comment: Did you check it? I work with WinRT + C++/CX every day and the debug output did often help to point me to the right direction, when a binding was wrong or when there was a type mismatch on a binding etc. WinRT seems to have a habit of silently ignoring exceptions/problems with bindings and to just report them via debug output (at least with C++/CX). So that's usually the first place I look at, when a binding does't seem to work or a converter doesn't get executed. Maybe you should also post the converters source code?

Comment: I waited until I got the RTM version today to verify that I still get absolutely nothing in the output window with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to declare any binding in the RadioButton.IsChecked. However, I did get this to work just fine through inverting the problem. There's an IsSelected property on FlipViewItem. I succeeded with this kind of approach:

```
IsSelected="{Binding ElementName=radioButton1,Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your converter does, but the common issue with `IsChecked` is that it is not a bool, but rather a `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`). Is that what your converter takes/returns?

Comment: My converter just returns Equals(value, parameter). The Convert method itself returns object, so I assume it would propagate to a bool? just fine. Casting it to bool? makes no difference. Like I mentioned above, the converter itself is never called.

Comment: But how does it convert back - IsChecked to flipView.SelectedItem? Mayb I have not slept enough last night, but I can't see how this would work with the binding. How about just doing what you are trying to do with a bit of good old code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not Bool? that you need. See (this works fine):

```
<Grid Height="150">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Boolean x:Key="MyBool">true</x:Boolean>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="true" Content="Hello World" />
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{StaticResource MyBool}" Content="Hello World" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Your problem is that converter parameters can not be bound values.

Comment: Good call on the converter parameter. I changed the code to use SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem. I then put in integers. Alas, it still doesn't do anything; I get no breakpoints in the converter hit. I get nothing in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/03/11/tips-winrt-converter-parameter-binding.aspx) describes a technique by which you can use bindings for ConverterParameters.

Key excerpts:

> ConverterParameter IS NOT a depency property but a “simple” object. In this situation you can’t use Bindings.  This side effect is true with all XAML platforms : WP7-8, Silverlight, WPF and of course WinRT.
>
> The idea is to create a dependency property on my converter and not using the ConverterParameter : To be able to create a DP, your converter must inherit from DependencyObject :

```
public class DistanceConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public UserViewModel CurrentUser
    {
        get { return (UserViewModel) GetValue(CurrentUserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentUserProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentUserProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentUser",
                                    typeof (UserViewModel),
                                    typeof (DistanceConverter),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> Then, I declare my Converter in my page resources :

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
  <conv:DistanceConverter x:Key="DistanceConverter"  
    CurrentUser="{Binding User}"
    CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
    MaxWidthAvailable="450" />
</common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
```

> And finally, I set my converter in my item Template :

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Fill="#00FF84" Margin="10,0" Height="10"
           Width="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.Distance, 
 Converter={StaticResource DistanceConverter}}">
</Rectangle>
```